# Air conditioner: Can I replace a 6-15R with a 6-20R?

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning

Can I replace a 6-15R with a 6-20R?

The old AC plugged into a 6-15R. New one needs a 6-20R. Can I swap?

Comment: Are these plug-in window units? If so, then most likely, "Yes" you can. If not, then all bets are off. If the plugs match and you're in the US, then yes. If you're in UK/EU/elsewhere, then I _think_ you're OK, but won't guarantee it (in the UK, I believe there's a fuse in the plug that's appropriate for the draw of the unit). How about you [edit] to give us the brand of the AC units, and pictures of the plugs, or just pics in general of what you're talking about. Without more details, all you'll get is pure speculation...

Comment: Absolutely not !!! You can run a 15 in a 20 circuit but not a 20 on a 15 circuit. The receptacles are polarized just like 120v but the rotated prong is on the other side or reversed imiage.

Comment: No, because a 20A receptacle requires a 20A circuit.  You probably don't have one.  You might be able to convert it to a 20A circuit if the wiring in the walls is 12 AWG or larger.

Answer (score 2):

6-15 is for a 15 amp circuit, 6-20 is for a 20 amp circuit.

If the breaker is 20 amp and the wire is 12 gauge, no problem.

If the breaker is 15 amp and the wire is 12 gauge, just need to change the breaker also.

If the breaker is 15 amp and the wire is 14 gauge, then both the wire and the breaker need to be changed.

The new A/C probably uses more amperage than the old one, so the need for a larger circuit.

If you have the old AC can compare the amperage both uses.  That will give a good idea if you need the larger circuit, or they just had the 6-20s handy/ran out of the 6-15s.

Comment: So a mfg just ran out? You have to be kidding, right? the listing of a AC unit includes simple things like this, they would not just run out, you can run a 15amp on a 20 amp circuit yes even the 240v are similar to the 120 rules but the sideways blade is on the other side so they can not be mistaken.

Comment: @EdBeal  These days not much left to be surprise about.  Don't expect it on a UL listed AC, but AC make is not named.

Comment: The white paper has requirements one of those is the power requirement I would absolutely expect this to be correct for the model. I have wired a few up over the years and usually install 20 amp circuits as they used to be more common and see table 210.21.B.2 notice no voltage this goes for both 120 and 240v circuits